# Inno Setup CreateInputQueryPage insert text between input boxes

Tags: inno-setup

I have created the following custom Input Query Page:

```
PasswordPage := CreateInputQueryPage(wpSelectComponents,
  'Installation Validation', 'Please enter either the password or unlock code to continue?',
  'This installation type is protected for licensing reasons. Please enter either the password or unlock code, then click Next.' + #13#10 + #13#10 + 'Installation ID: ' + FindVolumeSerial('C:\'));
PasswordPage.Add('Password:', True);
PasswordPage.Add('Unlock Code:', False);
```

Is it possible to modify the existing page to move the Installation ID from where it is currently above the Password input box and insert it above the Unlock Code input box or does this require a completely custom designed page? If so, what would be the best way to go about creating it?

Comment: It is quite difficult to say what is the best way for this task. For sure I can say just that you can modify that page. I would personally shift the *Unlock Code* to the bottom (by modifying `PasswordPage.Edits[].Top` and `PasswordPage.PromptLabels[].Top` properties) and create a label for that *Installation ID* which I would place in between ([`like this`](http://pastebin.com/aTBd72v1)). But that's just my preference. You could add it e.g. to the *Unlock Code* prompt and the actual prompt add after a line break. Or use a line break to make space for inserting a label. Or,... :)

Comment: Thank you, that is extremely helpful. I was unaware that you could add + #13#10 + line breaks to labels as well. This is what I am siding on doing, but it now opens up the possibility of changing the layout further and adding additional text in. Can the Installation ID easily be placed below the Unlock Code edit box instead of above it?

Comment: No. That cannot be done with line breaks since the label is autosized and *moves* the edit box down. So to put a text under the *Unlock Code* you would have to create a separate label control.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the code I decided to use in the end:

```
PasswordPage := CreateInputQueryPage(wpSelectComponents,
  'Installation Validation', 'Please enter either the password or unlock code to continue?',
  'This installation type is protected for licensing reasons. Please enter either the password or unlock code, then click Next.'
PasswordPage.Add('Password:', True);
PasswordPage.Add('Or Installation ID ' + FindVolumeSerial('C:\') + ' and' + #13#10 + #13#10 + 'Unlock Code:', False);
```